# Subcommand statement grouping?

Tags: bash

Today I tried this and was somewhat surprised to find that it didn't work:

```
$ nice -n 10 { ./configure && make ; }
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

Is there a way to use grouping in a "subcommand"?

Comment: The braces are bogus here anyway; you cannot nice the shell you are already running. (You can `renice` yourself, of course, but that will similarly affect all of the current shell.) In other words, `nice` affects a new process, and you are (attempting to be) not starting a new process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just pass shell syntax to the argv of a program and expect it to understand it. Specifically, the error you're seeing is because of the `&&` and `;`, which are "list operators" which separate commands. Bash is trying to evaluate the arguments to `nice` as:

```
nice '-n' '10' '{' './configure'
```

Bash then tries to evaluate the next command after the `&&` (`make`), then the next command, which is `}`. Technically, braces are both "reserved words" and "control operators". Different shells treat bare braces a bit differently but that's an esoteric detail. The point is depending on the shell that will either be a parsing error (like here), or an error due to not being able to find a command named "`}`" (usually the former.

Exceptions to this rule exist only within the shell itself. For instance, the Bash `coproc` keyword works like this, enabling special parsing and evaluation of its arguments almost exactly as in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this ? =)

```
 nice -n10 bash -c './configure && make'
```